# Benefits of asking on Wordpress Stackexchange instead of Stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion

In related questions, people agree that all WP-related questions should go into this forum, not stack overflow. But the fact is that there are 100k 'wordpress' tagged questions there, with more activity (views, votes, answers) than the questions in here.

If i post the same question here and on stack overflow (with the 'wordpress' tag), the one on stack overflow is much more likely to be answered.

So what are the benefits of posting a question here (besides keeping SO clean)? Because, everyone's gonna post the question where it's most likely to get a good answer (or any answer at least)…

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> If i post the same question here and on stack overflow (with the 'wordpress' tag), the one on stack overflow is much more likely to be answered.

Let's compare:

- WPSE has 70,983 questions with 18,827 unanswered, answered rate of **~74%**
- SO wordpress tag has 110,757 questions with 50,314 unanswered, answered rate of **~55%**

You are **significantly more likely** to get an answer to WP question here than on SO.

Also subjectively from my experience SO is way too prone to give non–WP answers to WP questions. I tend to see answers to WP questions there which are clearly lacking in WP–specific nuances.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the numbers!

Comment: Yet, my experience (based on a single example, 1 hour after posting) shows the opposite. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40630209/how-to-make-wordpress-turn-my-posts-into-objects-of-a-different-class-than-wp-po and http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/246372/how-to-cast-custom-post-type-into-separate-class-instead-of-wp-post - 1 answer vs 0, some comments vs 0, three times as much views - why is that?

Comment: Because life is rather random and it's not a good idea to judge anything by a single example? :)

Comment: Also this is a *perfect* example of what I said in my response. The answer assumes WP is OOP instead of telling you that what you're trying to do there isn't really a good idea in WP.

Comment: Oh and that one is also oblivious that `WP_Post` cannot be extended due to `final`. :)

Answer (score 12):

Adding to @Rarst's great answer I'd also say that (from my purely subjective) experience the quality here is much better. Just the fact that a question is answered doesn't mean the answer is correct, good, complete or conforming to WP best practices (which often collide/deviate from general standards).

So in any case I'd prefer waiting a bit longer for an answer but then getting a good and authoritative answer.

Comment: Sounds convincing!